# Extract files from tar directly into new tar

Tags: tar

I have a large `tar.gz` of a whole system (basically `tar czpf --one-file-system /mnt/usb/backup.tar.gz -C / .`).

I want to end up with a new `tar.gz` file that is just the contents of a subfolder (`./home`) but with all attributes preserved.

I could extract the files of interest with tar, and then re-compress the extracted folder.

```bsh
mkdir tmp && cd tmp
sudo tar xzpf /mnt/usb/backup.tar.gz ./home --strip-components 2
sudo tar czpf home.tar.gz *
```

This however has issues with the `p` flag (preserving permissions) and with other file attributes. It also requires enough extra storage to hold that whole directory.

I've seen ways to [recreate a new tar with specified files excluded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80239/efficiently-remove-files-from-large-tgz). One could repurpose that to exclude/delete all but the wanted files but that seems excessive. I've looked for an `include` option, but it seems that's not quite what I'm looking for. It only works on files on the filesystem, not for filtering a tar stream.

I've tried getting `bsdtar` to do the trick after seeing [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224835/how-can-i-filter-the-contents-of-a-tar-file-producing-another-tar-file-in-the-p), but I can't quite get the output folder structure to be what I want.

```bsh
bsdtar czf home.tar.gz --include ./home --strip-components 2 @/mnt/usb/backup.tar.gz
tar tzf home.tar.gz | head
./home/cameron/... # I want "cameron/..." (or "./cameron/..."). "strip-components" doesn't seem to work.
```

Comment: Curious question - you might have better luck getting an answer over at 'Unix & Linux'.

Comment: @user1138 I considered that, but `tar` is not just a "Unix & Linux" thing